# Injecting context into Spring MVC controller similar to Jersey InjectableProvider

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a custom InjectableProvider in my Jersey project that does some work with the request/session to conjure up a user id that my RESTful service needs. It means I can write service methods like:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getByAccountIdAndGroup(@InjectAccount(required=false) String accountId, @DefaultValue("default") @QueryParam("productGroup") String productGroup) {
...
}
```

Where @InjectAccount is my custom annotation.

I'd like to do a similar thing for SpringMVC controllers in the same project. That is, I want to be able to write:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model, @InjectAccountSpringMvc String accountId) {
...
}
```

I'm expecting to have to factor out the common code rather than re-use the Jersey InjectableProvider directly.

Possibly the more Spring-centric way would be to have a thread-scope bean injected into my controller, but am curious if the Jersey style can be done in Spring MVC at all. Using the thread scope approach, the injected service might look like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("THREAD")
public class AccountResolver {
   @Autowired
   private HttpServletRequest request

   private String theAccount=null;

   public String getAccount() {
      if ( theAccount == null ) {
         theAccount=resolveAccount();
      }
      return theAccount;
   }
}
```

This isn't as tidy and will make testing the controller directly more difficult.

Any ideas/pointers appreciated!

Alfie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can be done in Spring. You'll need to implement and register your own [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html).

The `supportsParameter` method will simply look for the annotation on the parameter. The `resolveArgument` method will perform the logic of retrieving the argument to use when invoking the handler method.